# Запись почты Gmail из папки "support" с меткой "unread" в Гугл таблицу

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Код рабочий. Но обнаружил проблему.
Иногда, как я понимаю, теряются данные. Письма в ящике помечаются как "прочитанные", но в таблицу не записываются. Наверное нужно записывать лог, а перед тем как помечать письма как "прочитанные" проверять были ли записаны данные в на лист в таблице.
Ребят, подскажите, как это сделать. Я только учусь .

```
function Gmail() {
 
    //this is just the stuff that recognizes what spreadsheet you're in
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2'); //gets the right sheet(указать название листа для записи)

    /* searches your GMail for emails matching things "label:unread" + " label:support"
    (support-это название  папки в которую собираются письма) */
    var query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; 

    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    var supportStats = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

        for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
            var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
            var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
            var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
            var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
            var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field(заменить на getBody для html) 
            var mId = messages[m].getId(); //id field to create the link later
   
            if (query === "label:unread" + " label:support") {
               supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
            }
            messages[m].markRead(); // помечает, как прочитанное
        }
    }
 if(!threads.length) return; //  если нет непрочитанных - ничего не делать.
 sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.
 length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet
}
```

Comment: Насчет ошибки - поставьте перед циклом проверку `if(!threads.length) return;` - то есть если нет непрочитанных - ничего не делать.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Все получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Сергею, за помощь.
Выкладываю доработанный скрипт,добавил некоторые комменты на русском, может кому пригодится.
Скрипт полностью работает. Время сообщений не отображалось из-за того, что в самой таблице в колонке стоял "Автоматический формат", сменил на "Дата и время" и стало ОК.
Значит, что он делает.
Копирует непрочитанные сообщения Gmail из папки которую укажите, в Гугл таблицу разбив по колонкам (from/to/time/subject/body/ссылка на письмо). После чего помечает их как прочитанные.

```
function Gmail() {
 
    //this is just the stuff that recognizes what spreadsheet you're in
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2'); /*gets the right sheet(указать название листа для записи)*/

    /* searches your GMail for emails matching things "label:unread" + " label:support"
    (support-это название  папки в которую собираются письма) */
    var query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; 

    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    var supportStats = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

        for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
            var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
            var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
            var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
            var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
            var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field(заменить на getBody для html) 
            var mId = messages[m].getId(); //id field to create the link later
   
            if (query === "label:unread" + " label:support") {
               supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
            }
            messages[m].markRead(); // помечает, как прочитанное
        }
    }
 if(!threads.length) return; //  если нет непрочитанных - ничего не делать.
 sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,1,supportStats.
 length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet
}
```